# How to make a result of a function the arguments of the same function atumatically in R

Tags: r

I am working on a complicated project, and each time I need to run my function using the result of the previous run of the function. To make my point clearer, suppose that I have a vector `x`, and a function `myfunc`. Then, I need to run `myfunc` using the vector `x`. Then, I take the output of my function and plug them again as an argument of the same function. I need to repeat this automatically several times.

For example,

```
x <- c(1,2,3)
myfunc <- function(x){
  res <- 2*x
  return(res)
}
```

Then,

```
x <- myfunc(x)
> x
[1] 2 4 6

x <- myfunc(x)
 > x
[1]  4  8 12
```

How can I do this automatically (repeat for, say, `5` times)? In the end, I need the result of the final run only. For example, the result of the fifth run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good way to do so would be to include an argument `repeats` in your function itself.

```
myfunc <- function(x, repeats=1){
  res <- x
  for(i in 1:repeats) {
    res <- 2*res
  }
  return(res)
}

> myfunc(x, 5)
[1] 32 64 96
```

Comment: The `repeats` inside my function is very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

```
x <- c(1,2,3)

for (i in 1:5) {
    x = myfunc(x);
}
```

outputs `[1] 32 64 96`, as does `myfunc(myfunc(myfunc(myfunc(myfunc(x)))))`.

Just keep reassigning in a loop?

Comment: Could you explain the semicolon?

Comment: The semicolon is just the end of the statement. I believe it's optional in R.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one liner. `Recall` allows for recursive calling based on a condition. Here I assume whatever happens in the expression in `my_fun` is vectorized, as `*` is. If it is not, wrap the function in `Vectorize`.

```
f <- function(n, rep) if(rep) Recall(n * 2, rep - 1) else n
f(1:3, 5)
[1] 32 64 96
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option with `reduce`

```
library(purrr)
reduce(1:5, ~ .x *2, .init = x)
[1] 32 64 96
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
x <- c(1,2,3)
myfunc <- function(x){
  res <- 2*x
  x <<- res
  return(res)
}
```

The double assign operator makes sure that your initial x gets overwritten in each function call.

Here‘s the result for 5 runs:

```
replicate(5, myfunc(x))

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    2    4    8   16   32
[2,]    4    8   16   32   64
[3,]    6   12   24   48   96
```

Comment: isn't non-standard evaluation overkill in this case?

Comment: I just found Patrick Burns' hilarious R inferno https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf: "Circle 6
Doing Global Assignments: Heretics imprisoned in flaming tombs inhabit Circle 6."